# How can I add some buffer to a mousemove event so it doesn't disrupt mouseup events

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm currently building a menu that is also draggable and I'm using the following on each individual tab:

```
(mousedown)="dragging = false"
(mousemove)="checkMouseMove($event)"
(mouseup)="changeRoute('forms')"
```

Change Route looks like this:

```
 changeRoute(routeName: string) {

    // manual reset for dragging.
    if (this.dragging) {
        return;
    }
```

Past this is just my routing and switch statement's that correctly will change route and apply styling etc.

Previously inside the `mousemove` event I just had `dragging = true` but the problem with this is that even the slightest movement will mean that a click does not occur when it's likely to be intended to.

My first instinct was that I need to add a buffer to the amount of space it will need to move to be called a drag but given the output events I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
checkMouseMove(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

This event provides me with the following output:

[image: Picture of output in console]

How can I use these events in conjunction with my checkMouseMove / Component to only change dragging after a reasonable amount of movement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the last mouse position and calculate the distance the cursor moved.
Based on this distance you can filter small and unwanted drags.

```
var lastEvent;
function checkMouseMove (event){
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;
    if (lastEvent) {
        dx = event.clientX - lastEvent.clientX;
        dy = event.clientY - lastEvent.clientY;
    }
    var d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));
    if (d > 5) { /* handle mouse move here */ }
    lastEvent = event;
}
```

You can also use any other non euclidean heuristics like Manhattan or Chebyshev.